# Is there a way to ensure that all data in a yaml string was parsed?

Tags: go, yaml

For testing, I often see go code read byte slices, which are parsed into structs using yaml, for example here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/util/strategicpatch/patch_test.go#L74m

I just got bitten by not exporting my field names, resulting in an empty list which I iterated over in my test cases, thus assuming that all tests were passing (in hindsight, that should have been a red flag :)). There are other errors which are silently ignored by yaml unmarshaling, such as a key being misspelled and not matching a struct field exactly.

Is there a way to ensure that all the data in the byte slice was actually parsed into the struct returned by yaml.Unmarshal? If not, how do others handle this situation?

Comment: Are you using `"gopkg.in/yaml.v2"`? Silent failure is very unGo-like... The encoding packages in the standard lib are all very strict.

Comment: Most decoders I went over with Go only treat syntax error as error. I think the way to handle is to have unit test coverage on yaml decoding on your struct. Or you'd need to write your own yaml decoder implementation.

Comment: Thanks Koala. I couldn't find a way so get it to work nicely, so I just ended up writing straight Go structs in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

### [go-yaml/yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml)

For anyone searching for a solution to this problem, the yaml.v2 library has an [UnmarshalStrict](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#UnmarshalStrict) method that returns an error if there are keys in the yaml document that have no corresponding fields in the go struct.

```
import yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"

err := yaml.UnmarshalStrict(data, destinationStruct)
```

### [BurntSushi/toml](https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml)

It's not part of the question, but I'd just like to document how to achieve something similar in toml:

You can find if there were any keys in the toml file that could not be decoded by using the metadata returned by the toml.decode function.

```
import "github.com/BurntSushi/toml"

metadata, err := toml.Decode(data, destinationStruct)
undecodedKeys := metadata.Undecoded()
```

Note that metadata.Undecoded() also returns keys that have not been decoded because of a Primitive value. You can [read more about it here](https://godoc.org/github.com/BurntSushi/toml).

### [Json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)

The default go json library does not support this currently, but there is a [proposal ready to be merged](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15314). It seems that it will be a part of go 1.10.